# Extracting data from tables without any grid lines and border from scanned image of document

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, data-extraction, document-layout-analysis

Extracting table data from digital PDFs have been simple using `camelot` and `tabula`. However, the solution doesn't work with scanned images of the document pages specifically when the table doesn't have borders and inner grids. I have been trying to generate vertical and horizontal lines using `OpenCV`. However, since the scanned images will have slight rotation angles, it is difficult to proceed with the approach.

How can we utilize `OpenCV` to generate grids (horizontal and vertical lines) and borders for the scanned document page which contains table data (along with paragraphs of text)? If this is feasible, how to nullify the rotation angle of the scanned image?

Comment: Post at least an image and your current code

Comment: having the same query, but the image quality and orientation can be fixed by using auto encoders and after that we need to try extraction

Comment: You can read pytessaract OCR to read data from scanned image of any document. You might need to do some preprocessing like grayscacle conversion, morphology operations or maybe connecting components analysis depending upon the situation. Please share your image so we can help you out ;)

Comment: Aleem is right ; I really would suggest using pytesseract and opencv for some preprocessing like: https://fazlurnu.com/2020/06/23/text-extraction-from-a-table-image-using-pytesseract-and-opencv/

Comment: Have you tried using Amazon Textract? I used it to extract all expenses from a scanned receipt in tabular form and it worked fine on my case

Comment: Is this for a job interview, by any chance?

Comment: I doubt that "take-home" job interview tasks run for an entire week, once the task is revealed. and if they do, I would _very much hope_ that the interviewer knows to check SO for the applicant...

Answer (score 3):

I wrote some code to estimate the horizontal lines from the printed letters in the page. The same could be done for vertical ones I guess. The code below follows some general assumptions, here
some basic steps in pseudo code style:

- prepare picture for contour detection
- do contour detection
- we assume most contours are letters

  - calc mean width of all contours
  - calc mean area of contours
- filter all contours with two conditions:
  a) contour (letter) heigths < meanHigh * 2
  b) contour area  > 4/5  meanArea
- calc center point of all remaining contours
- assume we have line regions (bins)

  - list all center point which are inside the region
  - do linear regression of region points
  - save slope and intercept
- calc mean slope and intercept

here the full code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

def resizeImageByPercentage(img,scalePercent = 60):
    width = int(img.shape[1] * scalePercent / 100)
    height = int(img.shape[0] * scalePercent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    # resize image
    return cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

def calcAverageContourWithAndHeigh(contourList):
    hs = list()
    ws = list()
    for cnt in contourList:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        ws.append(w)
        hs.append(h)
    return np.mean(ws),np.mean(hs)

def calcAverageContourArea(contourList):
    areaList = list()
    for cnt in contourList:
        a = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        areaList.append(a[2])
    return np.mean(areaList)

def calcCentroid(contour):
    houghMoments = cv2.moments(contour)
    # calculate x,y coordinate of centroid
    if houghMoments["m00"] != 0: #case no contour could be calculated
        cX = int(houghMoments["m10"] / houghMoments["m00"])
        cY = int(houghMoments["m01"] / houghMoments["m00"])
    else:
    # set values as what you need in the situation
        cX, cY = -1, -1
    return cX,cY

def getCentroidWhenSizeInRange(contourList,letterSizeWidth,letterSizeHigh,deltaOffset,minLetterArea=10.0):
    centroidList=list()
    for cnt in contourList:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        area = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)

        #calc diff
        diffW = abs(w-letterSizeWidth) 
        diffH = abs(h-letterSizeHigh)
        #thresold A: almost smaller than mean letter size +- offset
        #when almost letterSize
        if diffW < deltaOffset and diffH < deltaOffset:
            #threshold B > min area
            if area[2] > minLetterArea:
                cX,cY = calcCentroid(cnt)
                if cX!=-1 and cY!=-1:
                    centroidList.append((cX,cY))
    return centroidList
    
DEBUGMODE = True
#read image, do git clone https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/pdftabextract.git for the example
img = cv2.imread('pdftabextract/examples/catalogue_30s/data/ALA1934_RR-excerpt.pdf-2_1.png')
#get some basic infos
imgHeigh, imgWidth, imgChannelAmount = img.shape

if DEBUGMODE:
    cv2.imwrite("img00original.jpg",resizeImageByPercentage(img,30))
    cv2.imshow("original",img)

# prepare img 
imgGrey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# apply Gaussian filter
imgGaussianBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGrey,(5,5),0)
#make binary img, black or white
_, imgBinThres = cv2.threshold(imgGaussianBlur, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

## detect contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(imgBinThres, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#we get some letter parameter
averageLetterWidth, averageLetterHigh = calcAverageContourWithAndHeigh(contours)
threshold1AllowedLetterSizeOffset =   averageLetterHigh * 2  # double size
averageContourAreaSizeOfMinRect = calcAverageContourArea(contours)
threshHold2MinArea = 4 * averageContourAreaSizeOfMinRect / 5 # 4/5 * mean

print("mean letter Width: ", averageLetterWidth)
print("mean letter High: ", averageLetterHigh)
print("threshold 1 tolerance: ", threshold1AllowedLetterSizeOffset)
print("mean letter area ", averageContourAreaSizeOfMinRect)
print("thresold 2 min letter area ", threshHold2MinArea)

#we get all centroid of letter sizes contours, the other we ignore
centroidList = getCentroidWhenSizeInRange(contours,averageLetterWidth,averageLetterHigh,threshold1AllowedLetterSizeOffset,threshHold2MinArea)

if DEBUGMODE:
    #debug print all centers:
    imgFilteredCenter = img.copy()
    for cX,cY in centroidList:
        #draw in red color as  BGR
        cv2.circle(imgFilteredCenter, (cX, cY), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.imwrite("img01letterCenters.jpg",resizeImageByPercentage(imgFilteredCenter,30))
    cv2.imshow("letterCenters",imgFilteredCenter)

#we estimate a bin widths
amountPixelFreeSpace = averageLetterHigh #TODO get better estimate out of histogram
estimatedBinWidth = round( averageLetterHigh + amountPixelFreeSpace) #TODO round better ?
binCollection = dict() #range(0,imgHeigh,estimatedBinWidth)

#we do seperate the center points into bins by y coordinate
for i in range(0,imgHeigh,estimatedBinWidth):
    listCenterPointsInBin = list()
    yMin = i 
    yMax = i + estimatedBinWidth
    for cX,cY in centroidList:
        if yMin < cY < yMax:#if fits in bin
            listCenterPointsInBin.append((cX,cY))

    binCollection[i] = listCenterPointsInBin
 
#we assume all point are in one line ? 
#model = slope (x) + intercept
#model = m (x) + n
mList = list() #slope abs in img
nList = list() #intercept abs in img
nListRelative = list() #intercept relative to bin start
minAmountRegressionElements = 12 #is also alias for letter amount we expect
#we do regression for every point in the bin 
for startYOfBin, values in binCollection.items():
    #we reform values
    xValues = [] #TODO use more short transform
    yValues = [] 
    for x,y in values:
        xValues.append(x)
        yValues.append(y)

    #we assume a min limit of point in bin 
    if len(xValues) >= minAmountRegressionElements :
        slope, intercept, r, p, std_err = stats.linregress(xValues, yValues)
        mList.append(slope)
        nList.append(intercept)
        #we calc the relative intercept
        nRelativeToBinStart = intercept - startYOfBin  
        nListRelative.append(nRelativeToBinStart)

if DEBUGMODE:
    #we debug print all lines in one picute
    imgLines = img.copy()
    colorOfLine = (0, 255, 0) #green
    for i in range(0,len(mList)):
        slope = mList[i]
        intercept = nList[i]
        startPoint = (0, int( intercept)) #better round ? 
        endPointY = int( (slope * imgWidth + intercept) )
        if endPointY < 0:
            endPointY = 0
        endPoint = (imgHeigh,endPointY)
        cv2.line(imgLines, startPoint, endPoint, colorOfLine, 2) 

    cv2.imwrite("img02lines.jpg",resizeImageByPercentage(imgLines,30))
    cv2.imshow("linesOfLetters ",imgLines)

#we assume in mean we got it right
meanIntercept = np.mean(nListRelative)
meanSlope = np.mean(mList)
print("meanIntercept :", meanIntercept)
print("meanSlope ", meanSlope)

#TODO calc angle with math.atan(slope) ...

if DEBUGMODE:
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

original:
[image: original pic]
center point of letters:
[image: letter centers]
lines:
[image: lines]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago and [this tutorial](https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2017/02/16/data-mining-ocr-pdfs-using-pdftabextract-to-liberate-tabular-data-from-scanned-documents/) is the solution to that. It explains using [pdftabextract](https://pypi.org/project/pdftabextract/) which is a Python library by Markus Konrad and leverages OpenCV’s Hough transform to detect the lines and works even if the scanned document is a bit tilted. The tutorial walks your through parsing a 1920s German newspaper
[image]

Comment: The problem is that it still works by identifying lines. We are looking for solutions that would work well in borderless tables, for example: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-to-extract-the-non-gridded-table-from-the-scanned-documents

Comment: if you check the actual Github repo examples, there are screenshots of your use case as well
https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/pdftabextract/tree/master/examples